# What does this index error mean, " list index out of range on line 17"

Tags: python

So I am building a program where it has to print out each card from each suit in a deck of cards (11 represents a jack, 12 a queen, etc.). And the output has to show from 2 to 14 (which I don't know how to do). Here is what I have so far:

```
import random

DECK = 52 

suits = ['hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'spades'] 

card = ' '

suit_num = 0 

for i in range(DECK):    

    for cards in range(int(DECK/len(suits))): 

        print(str(cards) + ' ' + suits[suit_num]) #line 17

        suit_num += 1  

card = str((random.randrange(14))) + ' of ' + str(suits[random.randrange(4)]) 

print('Your chosen card is the ' + str(cards))
```

Comment: `print('Your chosen card is the ' + str(cards))` should be `print('Your chosen card is the ' + str(card))` (note: `card`, not `cards`)

Comment: Post the full traceback message - its easier to see the failing line. You seem to have spaces between each line... but that could be a problem posting here on stackoverflow. But guessing which is really line 17 is difficult (its not `suit_num += 1`).

Comment: You are having an `index out of range error` because you are going beyond the limit of `suits`.  ie.  `for cards in range(int(DECK/len(suits))): `  means that you are iterating up to the value of 13 but you only have 4 suits.

Answer (score 3):

@ScottC identified the issue in his comment.  One way to avoid these types of problems is to avoid using indices, and Python makes avoiding them very easy.

Here's a quick re-write taking out the indexing for `suits`.

```
import random

DECK = 52 
suits = ['hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'spades'] 

for suit in suits:
    for each_card in range(DECK//len(suits)):
        print(str(each_card) + ' ' + suit) 
        
card = f'{random.randrange(14)} of {random.choice(suits)}'
print('Your chosen card is the ' + card)
```

EDIT -- To return the desired output of 2 to 14, then one solution would be as follows, but it would mean that a deck of more than 52 cards (if that were ever needed) would need addressing.  Another question might be around jokers too.

```
import random

DECK = 52 
suits = ['hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'spades'] 

for suit in suits:
    for each_card in range(2, 15):
        print(str(each_card) + ' ' + suit) 
        
card = f'{random.randrange(2, 15)} of {random.choice(suits)}'
print('Your chosen card is the ' + card)
```

Comment: As per OP request:  "output has to show from 2 to 14"

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure whether to address that or not - let me edit to do so

Comment: The best explanation I've seen of Python's `for` loops (basically `foreach` loops in other languages) and how to use them idiomatically is https://treyhunner.com/2016/04/how-to-loop-with-indexes-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

There is only one list in your code, `suits = ['hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'spades']`, and this list has **4** elements. So, `len(suits)` is 4.

Look at the nested **for** loop:

```py
for cards in range(int(DECK/len(suits))): 

        print(str(cards) + ' ' + suits[suit_num]) 

        suit_num += 1
```

In theory, this loop runs **13** times, from *0* to *12*. In each iteration, `suit_num` gets incremented by **1**.
This is a problem because `suit_sum` is actually the index of the list `suits` in the line above `suit_num += 1` ! Since `suits` has size **4**, its index cannot exceed **3**. So, when the for loop runs for the *4th* time, `suit_num` becomes `4`, and you encounter a run-time error, "list-index out of range", because the list `suits` does not have an index greater than **3**!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid invalid indices we can use modulus or remainder (`%`).

```py
import random

DECK = 52

suits = ['hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'spades']

card = ' '

suit_num = 0

for i in range(DECK):
    for cards in range(DECK//len(suits)):
        print(str(cards) + ' ' + suits[suit_num % len(suits)]) #line 17
        suit_num += 1
print("="*40)
card = str((random.randrange(start=2, stop=15))) + ' of ' + str(suits[random.randrange(start=2, stop=15) % len(suits)])

print('Your chosen card is the ' + str(card))
```

(I just updated the code to match your 2-to-14 requirement.)